# how to cause button to automatically click it self

Tags: javascript, html

After a user click a button, the other button should click it self to display a inspirational quote. when the user click a button on the web page a quote will display. The other button should click on it self to automatically  display a quote on to the screen. The user should not have to click both buttons to get both quotes to display on screen. The user will click a button and the other button should automatically click it self to display a quote. I have been trying very hard to find a solution to a self clicking button, but with no luck. How do I get a button to click it self? Thank you for your help.

```js
let p = document.querySelector("#Quote");
let p2 = document.querySelector("#Quote2");
var messageButton1 = document.querySelector(".messageButton1");
var messageButton2 = document.querySelector(".messageButton2");

messageButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.textContent = "The Way to Get Started Is To Quit Talking And Begin Doing";
  //if user clicked the messageButton2,
  //it's this button turn to click it self to display message 
});

messageButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p2.textContent = "Don’t Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today";
  //if user clicked the messageButton1, 
  //it's this button turn to click it self to display message  
});
```

```css
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #63b8ee;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #3866a3;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #14396a;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #468ccf;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Self Click</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Other button self click it self</h1>
  <button class="messageButton1 myButton">Click for message</button>
  <span id="Quote"></span>
  <br><br>
  <button class="messageButton2 myButton">Click for message</button>
  <span id="Quote2"></span>
  <p>Cick only one button. The other button will click it self</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unlikely we need to see your css here. Could you please reduce this to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: why do you need 2 button separately? Is there any other action for second button?

Comment: I doubt you need it clicked. You could define both handlers and let them call each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this line:

```
messageButton2.click(); //Added this line
```

Full example:

```js
let p = document.querySelector("#Quote");
let p2 = document.querySelector("#Quote2");
var messageButton1 = document.querySelector(".messageButton1");
var messageButton2 = document.querySelector(".messageButton2");

messageButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.textContent = "hello";
  messageButton2.click(); //Addedthis line
  //if user clicked the messageButton2,
  //it's this button turn to click it self to display message 
});

messageButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p2.textContent = "Don’t Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today";
  //if user clicked the messageButton1, 
  //it's this button turn to click it self to display message  
});
```

```css
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #63b8ee;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #3866a3;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #14396a;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #468ccf;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Self Click</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Other button self click it self</h1>
  <button class="messageButton1 myButton">Click for message</button>
  <span id="Quote"></span>
  <br><br>
  <button class="messageButton2 myButton">Click for message</button>
  <span id="Quote2"></span>
  <p>Cick only one button. The other button will click it self</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the handlers separately and have both buttons call both handlers:

```
function setP1() {
    p.textContent = "The Way to Get Started Is To Quit Talking And Begin Doing";
}


function setP2() {
    p2.textContent = "The Way to Get Started Is To Quit Talking And Begin Doing";
}


messageButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setP1()
    setP2()
});

messageButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setP1()
    setP2() 
});
```

---

By the way, as the coder you have control over your components. You don't need to simulate user input to make stuff happen on your page